# How to get linked data from 2 collections with aggregation mongoDB

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new as MongoDB, I have 2 collections: `User` and `Video` with below structure. When user like a video, video's `_id` will be added to `liked_videos` on user collection. `liked_videos` is an array of _id

video collection

```
{
    _id
    mp4_url,
    liked_count
}
```

User collection

```
{
    _id,
    username,
    password,
    liked_videos: [ // videos _id array ]
}
```

How do I query to get the user's liked videos? Like below?

```
[
    {
    _id: 1
    mp4_url,
    liked_count
    },
    {
    _id: 2
    mp4_url,
    liked_count
    },
    ...
]
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `$lookup` to join collections and `$size` to get the array size

```
db.video.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "user",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "liked_videos",
      "as": "join_video"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      liked_count: {
        $size: "$join_video"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kvHOnxRZI14)**

Comment: Thank you, it works great. But if I want to get liked_videos from user1 only, how to update above code?

Comment: I will POST the user _id and then the result will show his liked video array.

Comment: I play around with your code and found the solution, thank you again.

Comment: @kien superb... Sorry for late reply... just bit busy

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

> ```
> db={
>   "video": [
>     {
>       "_id": 1,
>       "mp4_url": "url1",
>       "liked_count": 2,
>       "quantity": 2
>     },
>     {
>       "_id": 2,
>       "mp4_url": "url2",
>       "liked_count": 3,
>       "quantity": 1
>     },
>     {
>       "_id": 3,
>       "mp4_url": "url2",
>       "liked_count": 3,
>       "quantity": 4
>     }
>   ],
>   "User": [
>     {
>       "_id": 1,
>       "username": "almonds",
>       "password": "pwd",
>       "Likedvideos": [
>         "aaa",
>         "ffff"
>       ]
>     },
>     {
>       "_id": 2,
>       "username": "almonds",
>       "password": "pwd",
>       "Likedvideos": [
>         "qqq",
>         "bbbb"
>       ]
>     },
>     {
>       "_id": 3,
>       "username": "almonds",
>       "password": "pwd",
>       "Likedvideos": [
>         "ccc",
>         "ffff"
>       ]
>     },
>     {
>       "_id": 4,
>       "username": "almonds",
>       "password": "pwd",
>       "Likedvideos": [
>         "bbbb",
>         "ffff"
>       ]
>     },
>     {
>       "_id": 5,
>       "username": "almonds",
>       "password": "pwd",
>       "Likedvideos": [
>         "qqq",
>         "ffff"
>       ]
>     },
>     {
>       "_id": 6
>     }
>   ]
> }
> ```

Query :

```
db.video.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "User",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "data"
    },
    
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$data",
          "$$ROOT"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    "Likedvideos": [
      "aaa",
      "ffff"
    ],
    "_id": 1,
    "liked_count": 2,
    "mp4_url": "url1",
    "password": "pwd",
    "quantity": 2,
    "username": "almonds"
  }
]
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eRuNJyVChve)